# Filter data in Excel using multiples of a number

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I want to filter my data to only include values that are multiples of 12. So it should include 12,24,36, etc.

Is there a way to use the filter function so this can be done?

Comment: Add a helper column.  Identify the multiples of 12 there, then filter on that column.

Comment: I am sorry, but I haven't been working with excel for too long, could you explain what you mean by helper column and how this will help me?

Comment: A helper column is just an extra column you use to do some calculations.  Say your data is in Col A.  In B1 you could use a formula like: =MOD(A1,12)=0 and copy that down the data range.  For any multiple of 12, MOD(value,12) will be zero, so that expression will be true.  True and false evaluate as 1 and 0.  There are many formulas you could use to determine multiples of 12 (you would need to expand this one if your data contains zeros).  So now you have a column with 1's or True for multiples of 12 and zero or False otherwise and you can filter on that column.

Comment: @fixer1234, why don't you post that as an answer instead of a comment. You have my upvote.

Comment: Just made the connection--you want to use this for your other question about yearly averages--filter for years, then plug in your average formula.  If this approach works for you, self-answer your other question.  BTW, if that's what you want this for, you don't have to worry about zero values, so you can ignore the last section of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use a helper column (that's where you use an extra column to calculate something complex that you need for what you want to accomplish).  Since you want to filter on something that identifies multiples of 12, you calculate that in an extra column.

There are a number of ways to calculate that.  One is the MOD function, which gives you the remainder after a division.  Multiples of 12 will have a remainder of zero after being divided by 12.

Say your data is in Col A. In B1 you could use a formula like:

```
=MOD(A1,12)
```

and copy that down the data range. You can filter on results of zero.

If you want the results to stand out visually, you could turn this into a "Boolean" value:

```
=MOD(A1,12)=0
```

That creates a True/False test for whether the result is zero.  Multiples of 12 will produce a True result, all other values will produce a result of False.  You can then filter on True.  (If you format the results as a number, True and False will display as 1 and 0.)

If your data can contain the value zero, that will also produce a zero result if you test using the MOD function.  If you want to exclude that, you would need to expand your test calculation.  There are many ways to do this, but you could use something like:

```
=(MOD(A1,12)=0)*(A1<>0)
```

Another Boolean value--if A1 is not equal to 0, the last expression will be true, which evaluates to 1, keeping the expression, as previously calculated, the same.  If A1=0, the result of the last expression is zero, which would make the calculation zero like the non-multiples of 12.

So now you have a column with 1's or True for multiples of 12 and zero or False otherwise, and you can filter on that column.